# How do I move to directory "Program Files (x86)" with CD command?

Tags: command-line, bash, wine

When I try:

```
~/.wine/drive_c$  cd Program\ Files\ (x86)
```

I get:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: You need to put a \ in front of ( and )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2 methods (there are more):

```
cd "Program Files (x86)"
cd Program\ Files\ \(x86\)
```